# bootstrap popover goes outside the body when placement is left

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

Please take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/JW9cF/1/

You'll notice that the popover, if it has lots of content, will go outside the body at the top. Is there any way I can prevent this?

Also, for the second popover which has the placement "top" and it is near the left side, the arrow position is changed and the popover is not displayed outside the body. This is what I need for the first popover, to change the arrow position and keep it inside the body.

I'm using the basic popover initialization:

```
$('#element').popover();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it like this but I'm not sure this is the right way to do it:

```
$button.on('shown.bs.popover', function(e) {
    var $popover = $(".popover");

    if( placement == "left" && $popover.css("top").replace("px", "") < 0 ) {
        var arrowPosition = $(e.target).offset().top + $(e.target).height() / 2;
        $popover.css("top", 0);
        $(".arrow", $popover).css("top", arrowPosition + "px");
    }
});
```